# use jQuery UI accordion with a single panel?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I tried using it with a single panel, but **it doesn't collapse when it's single**, anybody knows if it is possible to do this and how ?

Comment: See [Stupid Simple jQuery Accordion Menu](http://www.stemkoski.com/stupid-simple-jquery-accordion-menu/) guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the [collapsible option](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#option-collapsible) to true when creating accordion

Comment: By the way, jQuery's greatly documented :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a collapsible panel instead of an accordion. Very simple to implement control.